# MPI_Scatterv segmentation fault when trying to send columns of a 2d vector

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a 2d vector of sizes NxM where N=13 and M=17 and 8 processes. I want distribute columns of this 2d vector to the processes, so p0 will have 3 columns while all the other processes will have 2 columns (all the columns will have 13 integers).
I can't se any error in my code, but it gives me segmentation fault when executing the MPI_Scatterv function.

This is my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 13
#define M 17

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int matrix[N*M];
    int menum, nproc, i, j;
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &menum);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    
    //Matrix initialization
    if (menum == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                matrix[(i*M)+j] = i * M + j;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Every process has its vector of size nloc*mloc
    int nloc = N;
    int mloc = menum < M%nproc ? (M/nproc)+1 : M/nproc;
    int *recv_vec = (int *)malloc(nloc*mloc*sizeof(int));
    
    //Create a custom datatype for a vector of nloc integers
    MPI_Datatype col_type;
    MPI_Type_vector(nloc, 1, M, MPI_INT, &col_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&col_type);
    
    //Distributing data to other processes
    int sendcounts[]={3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    int displs[]={0,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
    MPI_Scatterv(matrix, sendcounts, displs, col_type, recv_vec, nloc*mloc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    //Freeing up memory and terminate MPI environment
    free(recv_vec);
    MPI_Type_free(&col_type);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

I had to use `MPI_Type_create_resized()`, as mentioned in the comments, so the `MPI_Scatterv` can calculate the right offset for the following calls.

Comment: you need to `MPI_Type_create_resized()` your type so the second column starts at the right offset.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't the MPI_Scatterv know where to start the second column based on the displacements array?

Comment: The unit of displacement is the `extent` of the derived datatype. If you do not have the right extent, you will get the wrong byte offset, hence the need to resize the derived datatype.

Comment: OK, you're right, it works, thank you!